Problem while using scanner with libyara in C++
So, I'm using libyara in C++ and trying to create a scanner that scans a file against given yara rules and return if it finds any matches.
Here's the flow of the project -

A yara rules source file is compiled into a compiled yara rules file using compiler.cpp (my own c++ compiler made using libyara)
The compiled rule is then used in my scanner.cpp file to scan a file against the compiled rule file provided to it.

Here's my yara rules source file with a .yar extension -
rule AlwaysTrue {condition:true }
Below, I've attached my compiler.cpp and scanner.cpp files  (uploaded here in txt format cuz cpp isn't allowed)
scan.txt
compile.txt
And now, according to the rules file, I should always get a match as the rule is always true, but I get a unknown callback msg. as mentioned in my scanner file
Though, when I try to scan my file with yara cli using the same .yar rules file, it works and gives me a match.
Now I don't know where I went wrong but would appreciate any help:) (been stuck with this for 2 days now:/)
I compiled my code, and ran ./scanner but it gives me this output -

Initializing libyara...
Libyara initialized successfully
Loading compiled rules from file...
Rules loaded successfully
Creating a scanner...
Scanner created successfully
Setting up callback...
Scanning a file...
Callback: Message received with code -2052980432
Callback: Message received with code -2052980432
File scanned successfully
Libyara finalized successfully

whereas, it should give me a match to my yara rule instead of Callback: Message received with code -2052980432 Callback: Message received with code -2052980432

Put your source code as text in the question, posts should be self-contained.

It was too long, but here you go added it:)

The definition of YR_CALLBACK_FUNC is as follows:
typedef int (*YR_CALLBACK_FUNC)(
    YR_SCAN_CONTEXT* context,
    int message,
    void* message_data,
    void* user_data);

And your callback function has the following signature:
int callback(int message, void* message_data, void* user_data);

Which means your "message" is actually the address of the YR_SCAN_CONTEXT.
After fixing up the prototype of callback, I get:
Scanning a file...
Match found for rule: AlwaysTrue
Callback: Message received with code 3
File scanned successfully
Libyara finalized successfully


Can you please share the updated callback function that you have used here? Will be a lot of help

I just added YR_SCAN_CONTEXT* context as first argument to the callback.

Works now:) Very silly mistake of mine. Will make sure that I check the docs properly everytime :)
